# Allow X Client Display through TCP on Lucid

Tags: tcp, ubuntu-10.04, x11

On Karmic, to allow other PCs to open and X-Window on a station, one had to edit /etc/gdm.conf and change DisallowTCP to false. That file no longer exists on Lucid. I tried changing an entry in /etc/gdm/gdm.schemas (XML format) but that did not make a difference. 
 Any ideas on where to go for this?

Answer (score 2):

Make the following changes

1. Edit "**/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc**" 
    
   Delete **-nolisten tcp** 
    
   File content should have the following line 
   **exec /usr/bin/X "$@"**
2. Edit "**/etc/gdm/custom.conf**" 
    
   Add "**DisallowTCP=false**" line under the security section
3. Restart gdm
4. You are now listening port 6000 ;)

Dont forget to write "**xhost +remoteip**" in your local machine and "**export DISPLAY=localip:0**" in the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on natty but not on maverick...

The natty machine has /etc/gdm/custom.conf but no /etc/gdm/schemas, and I only had to change /etc/gdm/custom.conf to include DisallowTCP=false in [security] section to allow remote xterm display on the natty machine (and xhost +).

However, the maverick machine (on the same network) has /etc/gdm/schemas in addition, so I changed "true" to "false" in the following section:

```
 <schema>
   <key>security/DisallowTCP</key>
   <signature>b</signature>
   <default>false</default>
 </schema>
```

Also, /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc doesn't appear to be utilized in starting gdm, but anyway, I believe it's listening on port 6000 -- here's the result of netstat -an | grep -F 6000 on either machine:

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN

But I can't display a remote xterm on the maverick from the natty, while I can on the natty from the maverick...

Of course, ssh -X works both ways, but that's not what I need...

Answer (score 0):

On Karmic, you can change this entry in /etc/gdm/custom.conf, inside [security] section.

Comment: Yeah, that worked on Karmic, but not on Lucid.
Thanks though.

Comment: After you change /etc/gdm/gdm.schemas, you try to reboot ubuntu, before test?

<schema>
<key>security/DisallowTCP</key>
<signature>b</signature>
<default>false</default>
</schema>

Comment: I went in and also changed "DisplaysPerHost" from 1 to 2.
Rebooted, did "xhost +" and it works!!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't answer your question, but yes, I changed DisallowTCP and rebooted, did xhost + and it still did not work. I've tried some other changes, including adding a "custom.conf" file in /etc/gdm. I may not have remembered to do the xhost + after adding the custom.conf file though!! Hmmm....let me take that out and restest....

Comment: Nope. It works without the custom.conf file and also with the DisplaysPerHost still at 1. 
I must have forgotten to do the xhost + command when I tested it. 
So just setting DisallowTCP to false in the schema file worked.